# Install visual studio 2015 update 1 (not newest)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want install visual studio 2015 update 1 (just the update visual studio 2015 is already install)
I had download the ISO here [Link to download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=49989)

But when I launch the .exe the setup force to install Update 2 CTP 1 and not Update 1
How can I install update 1?

[image]

Comment: Here is the latest link where you can download the offline installer for the community edition with update 1 only. Make sure to disconnect your internet connection before installing so it will not check for the latest updates. http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/7/A/57A99666-126E-42FA-8E70-862EDBADD215/vs2015.1.com_enu.iso

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue yesterday...i could not find a easy way to do that, BUT...
They released a Release Candidate Version of Update 2.

I had installed it and do not have that issues (and bugs) from Update 2 CTP.

Link to download:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx). You can download the installer from http://my.visualstudio.com and run it with custom command line arguments. To install update 1, it would be `vs_enterprise.exe /OverrideFeedURI http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/2/A/32A1974F-D236-43C1-8981-97DDCBAEF14A/20160225.3/enu/feed.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You should see a notification for VS update 1 in the top right corner of the IDE. It looks like this:

[image]

Click this and select VS Update 1.

If you don't see it in the notification center, then go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and click on the Updates tab. You should see an item for VS Update 1 in the list.

Comment: that redirect to  https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs and download an .exe but the same problem appear

Answer (score 0):

if you have a need to install update 1, without installing update 2.

Download the offline installer, which is a ISO file of about 4 GB.
http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/C/1/4C113E0D-8590-47AB-B7B8-E41E0AD7936D/vs2015.1.vsu.iso

Open the iso and following folder
ServicedSetupPayloads\OfflineCache\installers\VSU_14.0.24720\en\0

There you can get the update 1 setup.

Answer (score -1):

You downloaded Update 2 RC.

The correct link to download Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 is here: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs